# How to communicate with wifi enabled camera

Tags: android, camera, wifi

I want to make an android app that communicates with a dslr camera and upload images to server from that camera using a wifi connection between android app and camera.

Can anyone provide me with a sample code or give me some links to get started 
Thanks in advance.